# string manipulation : how to split and join a string with delimiters include

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, vb.net, string

I want to split a string and join a certain string at the same time. the string that will be splitted is SQL query.
I set the split delimiters: `{". ", ",", ", ", " "}`
for example:

```
select id, name, age, status from tb_test where age > 20 and status = 'Active'
```

I want it to produce a result something like this:

```
select
id
,
name
,
age
,
status
from
tb_test
where
age > 20
and
status = 'Active'
```

but the one that I got by using string split is only word by word.
what should I do to make it have a result like the above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What's the logic of how you're splitting this?

Comment: you can first split on the SQL `commands` like `select`, `from`, ... and then you can further customize it

Comment: @VDesign if I split the SQL commands like select, from, ... then the sql command will be removed.

Comment: @Tri.PS See my answer to split on the SQL commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a list of all SQL commands where you want to split on:

```
List<string> sql = new List<string>() { 
     "select",
     "where",
     "and",
     "or",
     "from",
     ","
};
```

After that loop over this list and replace the command with his self surrounded by `$`.
This `$` dollar sign will be the character to split on later on.

```
string query = "select id, name, age, status from tb_test where age > 20 and status = 'Active'";

foreach (string s in sql)
{
     //Use ToLower() so that all strings don't have capital characters
     query = query.Replace(s.ToLower(), "$" + s.ToLower() + "$");
}
```

Now do the split and remove the spaces in front and end using `Trim()`:

```
string[] splits = query.Split(new char[] { '$' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string s in splits) Console.WriteLine(s.Trim() + "\r\n");
```

This will split on the SQL commands. Now you can further customize it to your needs.

Result:

```
select
id
, 
name
, 
age
, 
status
from
tb_test
where
age > 20
and
status = 'Active'
```

Comment: Add to `sql` list "," and will be expected result

Comment: yes... you were right. I get it now. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Reniuz  Thanks for the improvement reniuz. You were right. I get the expected result by adding it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure-regex solution:

```
(?:(?=,)|(?<![<>=]) +(?! *[<>=])|(?:(?<=,)))(?=(?:(?:[^'"]*(?P<s>['"])(?:(?!(?P=s)).)*(?P=s)))*[^'"]*$)
```

I made it so it can deal with the usual pitfalls, like strings, but there's probably still some stuff that'll break it. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fB5aH1/2).

---

Explanation:

```
(?:
    (?=,) # split before a comma.
|
    (?<! # if not preceded by an operator, ...
        [<>=]
    )
     + #...split at a space...
    (?! *[<>=]) #...unless there's an operator behind the space.
|
    (?: # also split after a comma.
        (?<=,)
    )
)
# HOWEVER, make sure this isn't inside of a string.
(?= # assert that there's an even number of quotes left in the text.
    (?: # consume pairs of quotes.
        [^'"]* # all text up to a quote
        (?P<s>['"]) # capture the quote
        (?: # consume everything up to the next quote.
            (?!
                (?P=s)
            )
            .
        )*
        (?P=s)
    )*
    [^'"]* # then make sure there are no more quotes until the end of the text.
    $
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used VDesign suggestion to solved the problem. I really appreciate your suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First split splits keywords SELECT, FROM, WHERE.
Second split splits all columns by using your delimeters

Comment: still `,` will be lost

Comment: @VDesign yeah, Reniuz was right. the comma still lost. is there any way to keep the comma only from delimiters?

Comment: If you have blanks after commas at any time, then you could remove the comma as delimeter

Comment: yeah, Reniuz was right. the comma still lost. is there any way to keep the comma only from delimiters?

Comment: but, sometime the user will type the query without space after the comma. something like select name,age,id,.... then if I remove the comma as delimiter that string will not be split.

Comment: replace all comma with comma plus one space then.

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution. But @Tri.PS I think you have to ask yourself if you just want a "simple" but messy split or if you want to write a lexical scanner that transforms your statement into a meaningfull block, splitting it into columns, where-clause-criterias, table-names etc and THEN finally implement a method to do the output like requested (but that would be a different task and a different question)

Answer (score 1):

One approach using regex:

```
string strRegex = @"(select)|(from)|(where)|([,\.])";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @"select id, name, age, status from tb_test where age > 20 and     status = 'Active'";
string strReplace = "$1\r\n";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

This should output:

> select
>   id ,
>   name ,
>   age ,
>   status  from
>   tb_test  where
>   age > 20 and status = 'Active'

You may want to perform another replacement to trim spaces before coma.
And also use "\r\n$1\r\n" only for sql keywords (select, from where, ...)

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used VDesign suggestion to solved the problem. I really appreciate your suggestion. Thanks a lot.